# MySQL maximum hit in one looping

Tags: java, mysql, max, hit

I have one Class ArrayList Named "Sentence". each Sentence contains value "Words".
I have to check each words into MySQL database whether it is a stopwords or not. Let say, i have 200 "Sentence" and each Sentence have a various number of "Words".

I've check the "Words" one by one into the database, when it hit over 2500 number of "Words" (sometimes it hits until 3500th Words before the connection fail), it turns Error. But it will be fine if the number of "Words" below 2500.

This is my Query code

```
public Query() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    try{
        cd = new Connect();
        connect = cd.getConnection();
        statement = (Statement) connect.createStatement();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Database connecting failed");
    }
}

public boolean isStopWords(String word) throws SQLException{

    String query = "SELECT stopwords FROM stopword WHERE stopwords = '"+word+"'";

    rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

    if(!rs.next()) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

This is my Connection code

```
public Connect() throws SQLException{
    try{
        Class forName = Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){

    }
    connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase", "root", null);
}

public Connection getConnection(){
    return connect;
}
```

This is my method to retrieve the Word from Class Sentence.String[] tempWords is the value of Words in one object Sentence. And the Sentence itself will looping according to the size of the ArrayList Sentence

```
protected ArrayList<String> eraseStopWord (String[] tempWords) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    result = new ArrayList<String>();
    db = new Query();
    for(int i=0;i<tempWords.length;i++){

         if(!db.isStopWords(tempWords[i])){
             result.add(tempWords[i]);
         }   
    }

    return result;

}
```

Why its fine until it hits approximately 2500 "Word"? (sometimes its fine until 3500th words before the connection fail, it just stable below 2500th of words)

UPDATE : now i know where the connection stopped. It stopped at 153rd sentence looping. so its not depend on the words. stil look after the bug

- I found the answer. i open the connection in looping, so MySQL take too much connection (152 connection)

Comment: Where you iterating and taking the values from arraylist?

Comment: i will edit the question

Comment: You should use interfaces when working with collections, i.e. `List` instead of `ArrayList` as return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. 
In my previous code, i make a connection everytime the Sentence created (db = new Query)

```
    protected ArrayList<String> eraseStopWord (String[] tempWords) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    result = new ArrayList<String>();
    db = new Query();
    for(int i=0;i<tempWords.length;i++){

         if(!db.isStopWords(tempWords[i])){
             result.add(tempWords[i]);
         }   
    }

    return result;

}
```

so, when it reach the 153rd sentence, it will stopped because of too many connection
The solution is write the open connection code before Sentence looping

Answer (score 0):

For words you can use a `in` clause.

```
String query = "SELECT stopwords FROM stopword WHERE stopwords in '("+words+")'";
```

This will reduce the number of hits. Better to make use of a PreparedStatement instead of Statement. This will save you from sql injections.

Comment: do i have to disconnect the connection or somewhat, i curious why its happen. is it any max hits limit in mySQL?

Comment: You can reuse the connection. You need not create new connection for each query. And yes you have to close the connection after the work is complete.

Comment: @Subir Beware of SQL Injection with this query!

Comment: @SubirKumarSao that solution is not work, my query stopped and failed to get connection to MySQL when it hits the 2646th words

Comment: In query allows only 1000 at a time. So you need to split after 1000 word. Post your current changes.

Comment: If you are getting to that number of words, rather than using an IN I would suggest putting the words into a temp table and then using a JOIN against that temp table.

Comment: UPDATE : now i know where the connection stopped. It stopped at 153st sentence looping. so its not depend on the words looping

Answer (score 0):

You need close the latest statement for query execution.

Look at line :

```
if(!rs.next()) return false;
else return true;
```

Change with this :

```
bool returnValue = true;
if (!rs.next()) {
   returnValue = false;
   statement.close();  // it will release the Statement object
}

return returnValue;
```

Comment: UPDATE : now i know where the connection stopped. It stopped at 153st sentence looping. so its not depend on the words. still look after the bug now